# Getting a 404 error with THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture and three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I'm trying to load a 3D model and use three.js for the first time.  I keep running into an error loading the textures.

```
loader.load('models/asteroid_OBJ/asteroid OBJ.js', function (geometry, materials) {
  var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({
    //map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('models/asteroid_OBJ/Map__4_Mix.tga'),   
    //map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('models/asteroid_OBJ/Map__12_Cellular.tga'),   
    //map: THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('models/asteroid_OBJ/Map__15_Noise.tga'),   

    colorAmbient: [0.480000026226044, 0.480000026226044, 0.480000026226044],
    colorDiffuse: [0.480000026226044, 0.480000026226044, 0.480000026226044],
    colorSpecular: [0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421, 0.8999999761581421]
  });
```

If I comment out the loadTextures the image loads properly, and functions.  If I don't, the image does not show up.  Either way, I get this error:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/models/asteroid_OBJ/-bm%200.800000%20Map__4_Mix.tga 404 (Not Found)
```

As far as I can tell the textures are in the correct directory aside `asteroid OBJ.js`

Comment: Can you show how you created `asteroid OBJ.js` (`convert_obj_three.py`?) and which loader you are using? A few other things to try: use an image format other than .tga (web browsers generally don't support .tga) and remove spaces from your filename. A separate problem is you're specifying the color parameters incorrectly for THREE.MeshLambertMaterial.
I'd recommend starting from one of the file loader examples on http://threejs.org/examples/.

Comment: @Squirrl just searched for tga support, maybe try this loader instead:
[http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/TGALoader](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/TGALoader)

Answer (score 1):

When i get this error, it is because i have forgotten to register .tga as a file extension in my Web.config file. Your Web.config file should look something like this:

```
<system.webServer>
             <staticContent>
                    <mimeMap fileExtension=".obj" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
                    <mimeMap fileExtension=".tga" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />

             </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```